# How to rank the winning ratio in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I've been building a classical Nim game with three java classes. So far, I build almost everything and the last thing I need to do is to rank the player in descending order by `winning ratio`, which is the `score` divided by the `gamePlayed`. What I've tried was to implement the comparables in `NimPlayer` class. Here is my code:

```
public class NimPlayer implements Comparable<NimPlayer>{ //initialize comparable
private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;

static int counter;
private int score;
private int gamePlayed;
private int winRatio = score / (gamePlayed+1); //avoid 0/0, mathmatically wrong

static NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[10]; // set an array here

//define NimPlayer data type
public NimPlayer(String userName, String surName, String givenName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = surName;
    this.givenName = givenName;

}
// create new data using NimPlayer data type
public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    if (counter<10) {
        playerList[counter++] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
    }
}
public static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
public static NimPlayer [] getPlayer() {
    return playerList;
}
// the getter and the setter of userName, familyName, givenName, score, gamePlayed

@Override
public String toString() {
    return winRatio+"% | "+gamePlayed+" games | "+givenName+" "+familyName;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(NimPlayer o) {
    return this.winRatio - o.winRatio;
}
}
```

In the main method, which called `Nimsys`, I've tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
    System.out.print('$');
    String commandin = in.next();

    if (commandin.equals("rankings")) {

       Arrays.sort(NimPlayer.getPlayer());//sorting with the object type           
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(NimPlayer.getPlayer()));
    }          
}
```

However, when I have two players in play and their `score` and `gamePlayed`are not null, the execution still goes to `NullPointerException`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code throws a NPE?

Comment: @donquih0te
`Arrays.sort(NimPlayer.getPlayer());` this one. I am sure that I select the object type put in the Arrays.sort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are initializating the array with a size of 10. The sort operation will traverse all 10 positions, and some of them will be null. If you create 10 players, then it should work without any problem.

To have a dynamic size, use an `ArrayList` instead, updating the following:

```
static List<NimPlayer> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {

    if (counter < 10) {
        playerList.add(new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName));
        counter++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
    }
}
```

For sorting the List:

```
Collections.sort(NimPlayer.playerList);
```

Besides this, I think you have some flaws in your code.

First, you are initializing the winRatio in the field declaration and, at least from what I can see in your code, is not getting updated never, so it will be always 0. A way to overcome this is to use the getters and setters to trigger the calculation each time you ask for the value.

```
public Float getWinRatio() {
    return Float.valueOf(getScore()) / (getGamePlayed() + 1);
}
```

Second, you set the winRatio as an `int`. This will ignore all the decimals in the divisions, so the results won't be accurate.

Also, you seem to be combining the data of players with the logic of the game. You should split the `NimPlayer` class from the logic containing all the players in the game.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. I did neglect the getter with the `getWinRatio`. May I ask what do you mean that I should split the NimPlayer class from the logic containing all the players in the game?

Comment: I mean that, in your class, a player has a list of players. That is not true, the game has a list of players. You can create a class NimGame or something similar in which you have all the logic of the game, like the players involved, the counter of players, and the actions that players can do